# Wrap content but with minimum width/height - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a Box and some Text in it. The Text is actually just a number, which can be 1, 2, or 3 digits. On the one hand, I want to wrap the content to accommodate for the case where we get a 3 digit number (which would make the box wider), but on the other hand, if we get a 1 digit number, the box becomes very skinny and looks visually awkward.

I've tried `Modifier.width(Int.dp)` and `Modifier.wrapContentWidth()` and even a combination of the two, but can't get it to behave right. Is there a way in Compose to wrap the content, but with a minimum (default) width or height?

I'd rather not use an `if - else` statement on the input size if at all possible, since that would sort of defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may use the `widthIn` modifier to specify a minimum width, while allowing the element to expand further if necessary.

```
@Composable
fun Foo(){
    Text(text = "1", modifier = Modifier.widthIn(min = 32.dp))
}
```

Comment: In my case, I am using Modifier.heightIn(min=x.dp), it always takes min set value and don't expand as per the content.